# How to locate mysql database on lan server...?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am developing Client-Server application(online examination) for Local Area Network.
I am using a MySQL database with vb.net.
I do not want to use a SQLServer database.

All is going good (working fine). I am going to have a client copy as well as server copy of the software. Client copy will use the remote MySQL database (which is on the LAN Server).

**What I actually want to know is :**

If I change the server in the future, then how to configure client copies of the software for database (changed server IP address)?

Answer (score 0):

Use a DNS name for the MySQL server, rather than using the IP address. Then, should you need to change the server IP address you update the DNS entry and your clients will use the new server.

Of course, if you anticipate this happening you should make your connection parameters easily configurable in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you already said it. All you have to do is make changes to your connection string to include servers Ip and port.!

Comment: I didnt get your question. Do you mean dynamically find the server and the then make connection to it ? in that case you will have to include DNS name. Look at @MiKe W 's answer !

Comment: I am thinking to modify My.settings.connectionstring (config var) by providing such facility to admin(lab in-charge)

Comment: so what the problem ?

Comment: some times,i found that admin person is not so knowledgeable person..(I wanted to handle such type of situations in the coding by application itself)